# How to get the most recent commits git values from git api

Tags: git, api, github

I can see that this repos has the most recent commit in Feb7 , 2014. https://github.com/wesm/D3py/network

[image]

but If I go to https://api.github.com/repos/wesm/D3py/commits? it only have 30 commits and missing the recent commits.
[image]
what I am trying to do is to get

branch_name , commit_date, commit_author , commit_parent , commit_child  for every commits.

any recommendation would help , thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub v3 API: Get full commit list for large comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420076/github-v3-api-get-full-commit-list-for-large-comparison)