# How to get list of commits between any two commits Using Jgit without cloning the repository?

Tags: java, github, jgit

So, I was working on a project in which I have to find the list of commits between any two commits, By cloning the repo, we can do it using simple diff, But I want to find a way in which we don't have to clone the full repo, and find the commits only.

Answer (score 0):

Even without JGit, you would still need to clone a repository in order to query its log history.

JGit uses [`git.log().addRange(from, to).call();`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48806230/6309), with `from` and `to` the [peeled object of the commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44693685/6309).

But that call is done within a *local* repository.

For anything involving a remote repository only, you would need the GitHub API, like its [compare REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits#compare-two-commits=), provided you are ready [to manage its pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70509725/6309).
JGit is likely not involved for that kind of call. A [`gh api` call](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) would.